# Automatically performing task when user notification is delivered in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift5, unusernotificationcenter

I want to perform a simple task in my app when a local user notification is triggered while the app is not in the foreground. Can I do this?

I can't use `UNNotificationAction`, because I don't want to rely on the user to do anything. And it seems I can't use `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` because it only has a method to handle notifications while the app is in foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have came to conclusion that what I asked is not possible. Here is my alternative solution: I wanted to perform an action within my app when a location based user notification was fired. To accomplish what I needed, I set up the monitoring for my `CLCircularRegion`. The delegate for `CLLocationManager` launches the app in the background upon entry to the region, and I can do what I want inside delegate method.